# Django 1.10 full text search by UUIDField returns DataError

Tags: python, django, postgresql, full-text-search, uuid

I have the following model:

```
class Show(models.Model):
    cid = models.UUIDField(
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False,
        verbose_name="Content ID",
        help_text="Unique Identifier"
    )
    title_short = models.CharField(
        max_length=60,
        blank=True,
        verbose_name="Short Title",
        help_text="Short title (60 chars)"
    )
```

I'm using the below snippet

```
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchVector
Entry.objects.annotate(
    search=SearchVector('cid'),
).filter(search='wateva')
```

Returns:

```
DataError at /meta/shows/

invalid input syntax for uuid: ""
LINE 1: ...unt", to_tsvector(COALESCE("entities_show"."cid", '')) AS    "s...
```

I tried with PostgreSQL 9.3.14 and PostgreSQL 9.5.3, Python 3.4.3

Has anyone encountered this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to file a bug-report.

The Django code creates a COALESCE() statement, assuming that the final fallback value of an empty string (`''`) is acceptable for fields given.
I don't see a way to specify the fallback value through the official API, and since UUID fields are translated to Postgres Native [UUID](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-uuid.html) fields, the empty string is an invalid value for that field.

If you decide to file a report, please add a comment here with the ticket ID, I might pitch in fixing it as I have a vested interest in this feature.